# Caching issue on linux OS between multiple processes

Tags: java, linux, caching

I have 3 java processes that runs on Linux and does database queries(MariaDB) and some file IO(Hard Disk and USB). Sometimes what happens is, write operations from one process does not get reflected on other java processes.

Two scenarios:

1. On completion of a INSERT query from process A, process A immediately launches another java process (process B), process B does not find inserted values in database.
2. Process A downloads a file from some server at a path X on a mounted USB. When download finishes, process A sends path X to process B via RMI. When process B tries to read file at X, it finds the file of 0 bytes. It happens only if path X is on USB, never seen this issue on Hard Disk. If I try to read file properties in process A before sending path X to process B, everything is fine.

I suspect there is some caching issue between multiple processes accessing data that is written just a moment ago.

More info : 
JAVA : 1.8 openJDK
Linux : Fedora/CentOS

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you commit the transaction? Is your JDBC connection on auto-commit?
2. Did you close the file before sending the path? If you don't close the file, it is still open for writing and the OS and Java will buffer writes. If you want to continuously write a file and make sure other processes see your changes, there are special API constructs for this, see FileChannel.force() or the synchronous modes of RandomAccessFile..

Comment: 1. No its not a transaction, its a straight INSERT query. I am not setting any auto-commit property on connection, what is the default value of auto-commit and more important, is it tide to performance if set to TRUE? Still I can do some queries into transaction.
2. Yes I am closing the stream properly before sending it to the other process. I'll defiantly give a try to  FileChannel.force() or the synchronous modes of RandomAccessFile, before that I need to first readup on these to make sure the performance issues as the the IO is happening on a USB.

Thanks, your answer helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all databases, only one process can access the files safely.  Often the database will lock the files to prevent access by more than one process.  It might be that this happens to work in some cases, but unless the database has been designed to do this, I wouldn't use this feature.

BTW: We have a database which is designed to do this so we know it's non trivial and rarely done.